# Multiple static IP - docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my first post so: Hello :)

I want to have a container connected to two docker networks on the same host.
I want to have static IP's for each network.
Networks are already created.
I was able to set a static IP with one network

https://pastebin.com/jnpFHSND

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
    homer:
        ports:
            - '7070:8080'
        volumes:
            - '/docker/homertest:/www/assets'
        restart: always
        hostname: homer-test
        networks:
          #default
            #ipv4_address: 172.19.0.222
          frontend:
            ipv4_address: 172.18.0.111
          # - kuma:
          #     ipv4_address: 172.20.0.222
          #- smtp
        container_name: homer
        image: 'b4bz/homer:latest'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy-manager_default
  frontend:
    external:
      name: portainer_default
  kuma:
    external:
      name: uptime-kuma_default
  smtp:
    external:
      name: smtp-relay_default
```

but with two or more

https://pastebin.com/axSaa0iJ

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
    homer:
        ports:
            - '7070:8080'
        volumes:
            - '/docker/homertest:/www/assets'
        restart: always
        hostname: homer-test
        networks:
          #default
            #ipv4_address: 172.19.0.222
          - frontend:
              ipv4_address: 172.18.0.111
          - kuma:
              ipv4_address: 172.20.0.222
          #- smtp
        container_name: homer
        image: 'b4bz/homer:latest'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy-manager_default
  frontend:
    external:
      name: portainer_default
  kuma:
    external:
      name: uptime-kuma_default
  smtp:
    external:
      name: smtp-relay_default
```

I get an error

> services.homer.networks contains {"frontend": {"ipv4_address": "172.18.0.111"}}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's usually not any reason to think about specific IPv4 addresses inside Docker at all.  Does your system work the way you want if you delete all of the `ipv4_address:` assignments (and just have a flat list of network names with no settings under them)?

Comment: In my case I had my database changing its IP address and Node-RED did not see it.
I know that you can point to the container by its name or a hostname but I prefer to set a static IP and not to worry about it. Once IP ( I prefer over 100 for static IP's) is set everything is cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a mapping in the first version, but in the second one you are using a list. Keep it a mapping.

```yaml
networks:
  frontend:
    ipv4_address: 172.18.0.111
  kuma:
    ipv4_address: 172.20.0.222
```

You can also review the [json schema for compose files](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/master/schema/compose-spec.json).

---

What do I mean by list and mapping?

```yaml
list:
  - a
  - b

mapping:
  a:
  b:
```

This would translate to json in like the below, which may make it more clear:

```json
{
   "list": [
      "a",
      "b"
   ],
   "mapping": {
      "a": null,
      "b": null
   }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the hyphens used in front of frontend and kuma. This will make it mapping from list and it will work.